# processing php tags inside a file/variable

Tags: php, tags, backend

I have lots of files that may or not have php tags (`<?php... ?>`) inside it.

first off, i need to check if the php tags exist in those files. no problem here. i use fopen, save the content to a variable, and strpos to do this.

next, if it has php tags, i save that to a temporary file and then use `ob_start()` include, and `ob_get_clean()` to save the output to a variable for further processing.

is there an alternative to doing this method? perhaps a more simpler one, like not having to save that to a temporary file but instead process it from the variable?

another alternative i have in mind is use fopen and strpos to check if the tags is present in the file and then use `ob_start()`, include (the original file), and `ob_get_clean()` to save the output to a variable for further processing.

any comments?

i would appreciate any response and/or comments.

btw, in case you might ask, i am working on a backend that accepts input from users that may or may not include php tags.

Comment: you might use regex after step 1. `preg_match('#<\?(php)?>(.*)(php)?\?>#', $data, $matches)` you would then have the contents of the <?php something ?> in $matches.

Comment: You can execute code from a variable using `eval()` but be warned if you use it with user inputs - It can be a huge security hole and often is disabled on shared hosting.

Comment: hikaru-shindo: thanks for your concern about security. be assured that only admin has access to this feature. further, security in general is not an issue as this is also being addressed. i have tried eval() but not what i needed. if an admin posts something with php tags (and saved as a file), the file is needed to be executed as if it was a built in php file wrapped around by built php files. thanks again.

Comment: on a tag note, your question doesn't really have anything to do with "tags" (markup language related) or "processing" (which is a programming language with an unfortunately chosen name)

Answer (score 0):

You question doesn't really mention what you're actually doing, so I'm assuming you're doing the incredibly dangerous "parse out code in <?php ?> blocks so that it can be run". Short answer: don't do this.

Okay I guess that's not an answer, more of a statement. But here's why: even if your users are all trusted users and they're all in your personal circle of friends and they're all experts, you only need one slipup to screw up the entire system. An accidental unlink()? too bad, now you're all screwed. And no, "we don't have to worry about that, everyone's cool" is not a good retort. Someone, at some point, is going to screw up, and the longer that takes, the more you stand to lose =)

With that said, it depends what you want to do. If you want to run it all in place, then just save the input to a temp file, include() that file, and then unlink() it again. The entire thing will execute in scope, and it will have been treated as if it was a normal PHP file on your system.

**warning** *THIS IS INCREDIBLY DANGEROUS, NEVER DO THIS ON A NON-SANDBOXED, PUBLIC SERVER, EVEN IF IT'S ON AN INTRANET. THIS APPROACH IS LITERALLY A FULL ANONYMOUS REMOTE ACCESS SOLUTION* **warning**

If you want to strip out the code and non-code to deal with them separately, as if they have nothing to do with each other, a simple non-greedy preg_match_all to find the code blocks, then doing an str_replace to kill them off in the original submitted content will give you an array of code blocks, and an input string with those blocks removed. Job done (although I'm not sure why you wouldn't use separate submission processes for the content and code in that case, since they'll be independent of each other).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way of doing it I can think of:

```
<?php
  function fileHasPHPTags($fileName) {
    return strpos(file_get_contents($fileName),"<?php")!==false;
  }
?>
```